# How can I convert comma-separated values stored in SQL Server to actual individual columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What type of TSQL statement can be used to read from data in Table1 (below) and produce the Expected Results (below):

With the following data in **Table1**:

```
ID      Field1      Field2      Field3
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       R1F1        R1F2        R1F3, R1F4, R1F5, R1F6
2       R2F1        R2F2        R2F3, R2F4, R2F5, R2F6
```

**Expected Results** A SQL Statement that would produce the following results:

```
ID      Field1      Field2      Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       R1F1        R1F2        R1F3    R1F4    R1F5    R1F6
2       R2F1        R2F2        R2F3    R2F4    R2F5    R2F6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks both a question and any indication of effort. The topic is readily amenable to searching for a suitable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `parsename` (limited to 4 parts only) or `string_Split` like below:

```
Select t.Field1, t.Field2
      ,Col1  = parsename(B.NewStr,4)
      ,Col2  = parsename(B.NewStr,3)
      ,Col3  = parsename(B.NewStr,2)
      ,Col4 = parsename(B.NewStr,1)
 From  @t t
 Cross Apply (values (replace(Field3,',','.') ) ) B(NewStr)
```

Metohd2:

```
;WITH C AS(
SELECT t.Field1, t.Field2
      ,value 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Field3 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Field3, ',') AS SS
)
SELECT Field1, Field2
      ,[1] AS Col1
      ,[2] AS Col2
      ,[3] AS Col3
      ,[4] AS Col4
FROM C
PIVOT(
    MAX(VALUE)
    FOR RN IN([1],[2],[3],[4])  
) as PVT
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9417384eb5beb2a1a55a905eec6facd8)**.

Comment: If no more than 4 columns, PARSENAME() is the way to go.  +1